# Join keys and values in perl

Tags: perl

I have a hash with the following key/value pair

```
4 => model1
2 => model2
```

I want the following string created from the above hash

```
4 X model1 , 2 X model2
```

I tried the following

```
my %hash,
foreach my $keys (keys %hash) {
    my $string = $string . join(' X ',$keys,$hash{$keys});
}
print $string;
```

What I get is

```
4 X model12Xmodel2
```

How can I accomplish the desired result `4 X model1 , 2 X model2`?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You could do:

```
my %hash = (4 => "model1", 2 => "model2");
my $str = join(", ", map { "$_ X $hash{$_}" } keys %hash);
print $str;
```

Output:

```
4 X model1, 2 X model2
```

How it works:

`map { expr } list` evaluates `expr` for every item in `list`, and returns the list that contains all the results of these evaluations. Here, `"$_ X $hash{$_}"` is evaluated for each key of the hash, so the result is a list of `key X value` strings. The `join` takes care of putting the commas in between each of these strings.

---

Note that your hash is a bit unusual if you're storing (item,quantity) pairs. It would usually be the other way around:

```
my %hash = ("model1" => 4, "model2" => 2);
my $str = join(", ", map { "$hash{$_} X $_" } keys %hash);
```

because with your scheme, you can't store the same quantity for two different items in your hash.

Comment: Thanks. my original hash is just like what you have mentioned. I tried to reverse it so I can get the count in the key. However, I do get your point that reversing is an disadvantage as I can store unique items.

Comment: If you want a (quantity -> item) map, you can do it, but you'll need a hash-of-arrays. Syntax gets a bit tricky though. http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html#Generation-of-a-HASH-OF-ARRAYS

Answer (score 1):

You can also modify your loop as follows:

```
my @tokens =();
foreach my $key (keys %hash) {
     push @tokens, $string . join(' X ',$key, $hash{$key});
}
print join(', ' , @tokens);
```